# jQuery Question on Saving Elements to DOM and Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am working on a project and I am using jQuery Tabs like the image below.  I installed an Inline Edit script to modify the text, and delete if needed.  There is no database involved at this point, I have a VIN decoder script and it pulls the default features and they can edit it if needed, and it edits in the DOM.  It works perfectly but when I switch tabs to "Interior" and then go back to "Exterior" then the exterior content goes back to the original list and none of the updates were saved.

And this is probably because the main page is at **add-vehicle.php** and on that page this is how I get the content:

```
<div id="tabContent">
        <div id="contentHolder">
            <!-- The AJAX fetched content goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the content is on **features.php**

[image]

```
var Tabs = {
    'Mechanical'    : 'features.php?feature=MECHANICAL&vin='+vin+'',
    'Exterior'  : 'features.php?feature=EXTERIOR&vin='+vin+'',
    'Interior'  : 'features.php?feature=INTERIOR&vin='+vin+'',
    'Safety'    : 'features.php?feature=SAFETY&vin='+vin+'',
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this?  What I want to happen is all of the inline edits will be saved, and I can switch through the differnet tabs and make those changes, and everything will be saved.

Not sure how well I explained this, please let me know if you need to see more code.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit more complicated than you probably expect, you are removing the forms from the DOM before any data is saved.

When the code is loaded back in for each tab, you are starting over with the forms.

You can fix this a few ways:

- Store the content of each tab in the DOM after it is loaded and just hide it when the tab is not in view.
- When each tab is "unloaded", store the data in JavaScript and place it back in the tab when that tab is loaded.
- Allow the save buttons on each tab to save all the information server-side and when the tab is retrieved to populate the forms server-side.

Comment: Thank you Shawn.  I like option #1 storing the content in each tab in the DOM after it is loaded and hiding it when it's not in view.  Can you guide me in the right direction on starting that code?

Comment: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sweet-tabs-jquery-ajax-css/  - THANK YOU, this has been driving me crazy I appreciate your help.

Comment: I updated it a little bit, here is my javascript for it: http://pastebin.com/pnrMU0h2

Comment: I know, I updated the link right away as soon as I realized  it.

Comment: Try this...coded it blindly (no testing), so no promises.  At least it should get you a step in the right direction: http://pastebin.com/PAvxuGXY

Comment: Ah, try commenting out "$('#contentHolder').html('<img src="images/ajax_preloader.gif" width="64" height="64" class="preloader" />');" and see if it works.

Comment: That helped.  Now when you click through all the tabs it works but when you click back to another tab, it adds it to the bottom so when you click all 4 AGAIN then you have one tab with all 4 features and the headings listed.  I can send you a demo link if you have a messenger or something.  I appreciate the help I don't mind paying you if we can get this figured out.